# How to get the same effect in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Could you tell me how to get the same effect in tkinter as we do in HTML using

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
<option value="Option1">
<option value="Option2">
<option value="Option3">
</datalist>
```

Comment: have a look at the `ttk.Combobox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a Tk dropdown, this is best implemented using an `OptionMenu`. An example of this can be found [here](https://pythonspot.com/tk-dropdown-example/).

Comment: You're welcome! If this answers your question fully, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).